# Node.JS String encoding issues

Tags: mysql, node.js, encoding, tcp

I'm writing a sort of interface between a TCP Chat server and an SQL Server, and while working on a part where a user submits a value and is assigned a named pulled from a row in this DB with this value. When querying this DB with a value from a telnet shell, I can't get any results from the DB. But I can when I perform the same query in adminer/MySQL @ BASH etc...
My thoughts are that it has come down to an encoding issue. Being rather noobish to node, I don't really know what to do. I do have a pretty good experience with JavaScript, just not node.

**Code**

```
function setCliNameOrKick(client, key){
key = String(key).replace(/\n\r\b\\\s/gi, "");
var q = "SELECT username FROM webusers WHERE lic = \'"+String(key).toString()+"\'; --";
console.log(key);
query(q);
cli.query(q, function cb(e, r, f){
    if(client != null){
        console.log(r);
        if(r.length >= 1){
            client.name = r['username'];
        }else{
            client.stream.end();
        }
    }else{
        console.log("Was Passed A Null Client!");
    }

});
}
```

That comes from the DB query tool
It takes input from a string sent by the client on connect, alongside an object representing the client

```
 stream.addListener("data", function(data){
    if(client.name == null){
        data = String(data).replace(new RegExp("[\n]+", "g"), "");
        cNameBuff = cNameBuff + data;
        if(cNameBuff.length > 1){ //Min Length
            //client.name = cNameB;
            db.set(client, cNameBuff);
            onAuth(client);
        }
        return;
    }
    data = String(data);
    if(data.length >= 2){
        srv.procChat(client, data);   
    }
});
```

Comment: node is emitting the json string right? If so, can we see some code?  I'd expect you to be using JSON.stringify.

Comment: JSON really is not part of the question, if I know what your asking. The only time it really comes in is in the response from the SQL server, which is no problem to process. It's actually sending the data to the server that's a problem, the server gets the data, but can't pull any rows/columns

Comment: soz dude i got json on the brain today :D

Comment: No problem. It is an interesting utility for data storage. I'm an XML man myself, though :P